# How do I call an Oracle stored procedure from WebMatrix?

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to execute an oracle stored procedure using WebMatrix.Data from Microsoft's WebMatrix. I can get data just fine with normal select statements...but I can't for the life of me figure out how to execute an oracle proc. It's not executed like a T-SQL proc I know that. Please help!

I'm trying to get a single value back. I'm just trying to prove that I can access an oracle stored proc with webmatrix.data. It is a query so I'm not sure db.Execute would work since that is for non-queries.

here's the code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COUNT_JOB_HISTORY
 (
   reccount OUT NUMBER
 )
 IS
   BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO reccount
     FROM JOB_HISTORY;
   END COUNT_JOB_HISTORY;
```

Here's the .Net code

```
    public static dynamic GetJobHistoryCount()
    {
        var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName);

        var jobs = db.QueryValue("exec COUNT_JOB_HISTORY(:0)", "count");

        return jobs;
    }
```

It blows up as an ORA-00900 : invalid SQL statement

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `db.Execute()` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.execute%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)...

Regardings the procedure itself and dealing with params/result it is hard to tell because you did not provide enough information like

What exactly does the procedure return ? one value ? one row ? a cursor ?

EDIT- after the OP showed the Stored Procedure:

Every Stored Procedure is a "Non-Query" - WebMatrix does not know anything about what happens inside the Stored Procedure...
I never used WebMatrix... so this is only a guess:

```
int reccount = 0;
db.Execute ("COUNT_JOB_HISTORY", reccount);
```

or perhaps

```
db.Execute ("COUNT_JOB_HISTORY", ref reccount);
```

**EDIT 2 - another try:**

```
db.Execute ("BEGIN COUNT_JOB_HISTORY(:0); END;", reccount);
```

Comment: Hello! I edited my original question to be more specific. Hope this helps! Thanks again for any help you can give

Comment: Okay! We are definately getting there! Thanks to you it stopped throwing that error! :-) Now, however since it's returned as a dynamic collection, it's only outputting once char. So instead of returning the number 10, it only returns the number 1. Any thoughts? Thanks again !

Comment: It return 1 because Execute is supposed to return the count of "changed rows" not any values...

Comment: One last try - this time with `db.Query ("BEGIN COUNT_JOB_HISTORY(:0); END;", reccount);` - perhaps this works

Comment: Unfortunately it returned 0 records when using db.Query. I do appreciate all your help. Thanks

Comment: 0 records is/could be ok - what does the procedure itself return (executed from "SQL Plus" for example ?

Comment: since I don't use WebMatrix I think this is as far as I gonna get with this... sorry that this is sort of "half solved"...